# Pass string arguments to Matlab mex command

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm using a `mex` command to build my C code contained in `sfun.c`:

```
mex CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=gnu99" sfun.c;
```

This works as expected. However, I'd like to change the portion `CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=gnu99"` programmatically. I tried assigning this portion to a variable and passing it to `mex` command as followed, but it failed:

```
bv = 'CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=gnu99"'
mex bv sfun.c
```

Matlab returns this error:

```
gcc: error: bv: No such file or directory

mex: compile of ' "sfun.c"' failed.
```

What would be the closest way to programmatically generate `bv` and passing that value to the `mex` command?

Comment: If you found a solution I'd appreciate it if you shared it.

Answer (score -1):

You want

```
mex(bv, 'sfun.c');
```

In general,

```
foo bar baz
```

Is treated the same as

```
foo('bar', 'baz')
```

So your command was passing the literal string 'bv' to mex.

Comment: This does not work. Tried the suggestion and a few variations with no success in R2017a.

Comment: @Ian, I'm not sure what trouble you had, but this definitely works.

`>> disp(version)`
9.2.0.556344 (R2017a)
`>> bv = 'CFLAGS="\$CFLAGS -std=gnu99"'; mex(bv,'sfun.c')`
Building with 'gcc'.
MEX completed successfully.
`>> sfun`
Hello world

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668913/how-to-pass-filepath-variables-to-mex-command That is where we solved the issue. I tried yours again with no success, so I don't know.

Comment: @Ian - Ok, I added an answer to that question which hopefully helps explain why what you were trying wasn't working for you. Nevertheless, my answer here does solve the original user's question, so I hope you'll consider un-downvoting it.