# How to pass filepath variables to mex command?

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

Currently trying to create a minimal example of scripted mex file generation.

I have a MATLAB .m script that I am running to generate mex files. I would like to pass in all the arguments as variables so that I can automate a bunch of mex file construction when given a list of filenames/paths.

```
#1 : unknown argument -outdir
input = ' -outdir C:/Users/ian/mexTesting/mexFiles'
mex('src/helloworld.cpp', input)

#2 : unknown filepath / can't find location (interprets entire string as path to mex file)
input = 'src/helloworld.cpp -outdir C:/Users/ian/mexTesting/mexFiles'
mex(input)

#3 : same issue as #2
mex input

#4 : Works, but no variables included, so no easy way to automate
mex src/helloworld.cpp -outdir /mexFiles
```

All of these (except #4) get either unknown argument -outdir or it interprets the input char arr as a path to a mex file.

Does anyone know how to pass variables into the mex command?

There are no questions that have actually answered this issue that I could find. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
input = 'src/helloworld.cpp';
output = '/mexFiles';

eval(['mex ' input ' -outdir ' output]);
```

Comment: Wicked, thanks man! Out of curiosity, does the [x ' ' y ' '] syntax create a character array with the variables / const char arrays? I'm not really sure as to why that works, but passing in a variable to the mex command directly does not.

Comment: Well its purpose is to concatenate character arrays, yes. It is very useful when dealing with parametrized strings.

Answer (score 2):

When executing a command of the form

```
func arg1 arg2 arg3
```

MATLAB treats this the same as

```
func('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')
```

Contrariwise, when you do something like

```
input = ' -outdir C:/Users/ian/mexTesting/mexFiles'
mex('src/helloworld.cpp', input)
```

It's the same as if you had run

```
mex src/helloworld.cpp ' -outdir C:/Users/ian/mexTesting/mexFiles'
```

Which is *not* the same as

```
mex src/helloworld.cpp -outdir C:/Users/ian/mexTesting/mexFiles
```

If you wanted to parameterize the arguments to MEX, you need to keep each space-delimited argument in a separate string. So, for example, you could use

```
outdirArg = 'C:/Users/ian/mexTesting/mexFiles';
mex('src/helloworld.cpp', '-outdir', outdirArg);
```

If you want to batch a bunch of arguments in a single variable, you could use a cell array and comma-separated list expansion, which would look like this:

```
args = {'-outdir', 'C:/Users/ian/mexTesting/mexFiles'};
mex('src/helloworld.cpp', args{:});
```

Comment: I'll upvote it here, cause apparently the other one was two days ago.